# Increasing the label size in matplotlib in pie chart

Tags: matplotlib, data-visualization, pie-chart

I have the following dictionary

```
{'Electronic Arts': 66,
 'GT Interactive': 1,
 'Palcom': 1,
 'Fox Interactive': 1,
 'LucasArts': 5,
 'Bethesda Softworks': 9,
 'SquareSoft': 3,
 'Nintendo': 142,
 'Virgin Interactive': 4,
 'Atari': 7,
 'Ubisoft': 28,
 'Konami Digital Entertainment': 11,
 'Hasbro Interactive': 1,
 'MTV Games': 1,
 'Sega': 11,
 'Enix Corporation': 4,
 'Capcom': 13,
 'Warner Bros. Interactive Entertainment': 7,
 'Acclaim Entertainment': 1,
 'Universal Interactive': 1,
 'Namco Bandai Games': 7,
 'Eidos Interactive': 9,
 'THQ': 7,
 'RedOctane': 1,
 'Sony Computer Entertainment Europe': 3,
 'Take-Two Interactive': 24,
 'Square Enix': 5,
 'Microsoft Game Studios': 22,
 'Disney Interactive Studios': 2,
 'Vivendi Games': 2,
 'Sony Computer Entertainment': 52,
 'Activision': 45,
 '505 Games': 4}
```

Now the problem I am facing is viewing the labels. The labels are extremely small and invisible.
Please anyone can suggest on how to increase the label size.
I have tried the below code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(80,80))
plt.pie(vg_dict.values(),labels=vg_dict.keys())
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding `textprops` argument in `plt.pie` method:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(80,80))
plt.pie(vg_dict.values(), labels=vg_dict.keys(), textprops={'fontsize': 30})
plt.show()
```

You can check all the properties of `Text` object [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text).

#### Updated

I don't know if your labels order matter? To avoid overlapping labels, you can try to modify your start angle (`plt` start drawing pie counterclockwise from the x-axis), and re-order the "crowded" labels:

```
vg_dict = {
    'Palcom': 1,
    'Electronic Arts': 66,
    'GT Interactive': 1,
    'LucasArts': 5,
    'Bethesda Softworks': 9,
    'SquareSoft': 3,
    'Nintendo': 142,
    'Virgin Interactive': 4,
    'Atari': 7,
    'Ubisoft': 28,
    'Hasbro Interactive': 1,
    'Konami Digital Entertainment': 11,
    'MTV Games': 1,
    'Sega': 11,
    'Enix Corporation': 4,
    'Capcom': 13,
    'Acclaim Entertainment': 1,
    'Warner Bros. Interactive Entertainment': 7,
    'Universal Interactive': 1,
    'Namco Bandai Games': 7,
    'Eidos Interactive': 9,
    'THQ': 7,
    'RedOctane': 1,
    'Sony Computer Entertainment Europe': 3,
    'Take-Two Interactive': 24,
    'Vivendi Games': 2,
    'Square Enix': 5,
    'Microsoft Game Studios': 22,
    'Disney Interactive Studios': 2,
    'Sony Computer Entertainment': 52,
    'Fox Interactive': 1,
    'Activision': 45,
    '505 Games': 4}
```

```
plt.figure(figsize=(80,80))
plt.pie(vg_dict.values(), labels=vg_dict.keys(), textprops={'fontsize': 35}, startangle=-35)
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: It s working but one issue i am having is over lapping labels,some labels are overlapping as the pie is very small.

Comment: Hey @PythonLearner, I have updated the post.